# How to stop React component from re-fetching data on load when hitting browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm using Next.js and `Next Link` to handle routing in my React app.

Let's say I have the 2 pages: `/product-list?year=2020` and a detailed page which will be routed to `/product-list/details?year=2020&month=4`

In `pages/product-list.js`, I use React router to get the `year` query param to make an API call.

```
const ProductList = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const year = router.query.year;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch API using year
  }, [year]);

  return (
    // UI
    <Link href="/product-list/details/?year=2020&month=4" />
  );
}
```

When I navigate back from the detailed page by clicking the back button, I can see that not the whole page is rendered (verified by setting the background of the page using the Dev Console to yellow and verified it didn't change when going back).

However, it did trigger another (unnecessary) API call since the router notified my `ProductList` component that the `year` variable changed... which technically it did...

So the question is: is there any way to not trigger the `year` variable change notification *only* when coming back from another page? (think how iOS app keeps the navigation stack in memory and when you pop back the previous page isn't necessarily rendered again).

Answer (score -1):

One way is to re-render would be to change the state variable on the submission of the Axios request causing the component to re-render automatically.

Answer (score -1):

**swr is the best option by vercel for better performance on data fetching and maintain state for fetched data**